# How to execute SonarQube analysis on Apache Hive SQL code?

Tags: sql, hive, sonarqube

Is there a way or plugin in SonarQube to evaluate the Apache Hive or Spark SQL SQL codes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most known SonarQube plugins are listed on the [Plugins space of the official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG). But no such plugin is listed there.

And doing a quick Google search tends to indicate that nobody ever created such a plugin.